# Installing a device driver programmatically

Tags: c#, installation, device-driver, inf, getlasterror

i need to install a device driver (INF file) through c#. I used the function **UpdateDriverForPlugAndPlayDevices**. However, it returns me **FALSE**, but the GetLastError() returns a value **0**, which indicates Success message for the installation. 
Not sure if i am proceeding in the correct way or not.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance,
P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the source for [devcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It is available in the WDK and is exactly what you need. Specifically look for the way that [devcon will install an INF file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544724%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I still use the Windows 7 WDK, and it's located at `C:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\setup\devcon`.

You'll probably find it's [using the `SetupCopyOEMInf()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which you should try using from your C# application too.

Comment: A more detailed answer with code sample can be found here [How to use SetupCopyOEMInf during installer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404660/how-to-use-setupcopyoeminf-during-installer)

Answer (score 2):

This simple code worked for me

```
    private void driverInstall()
    {

        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c C:\\Windows\\System32\\InfDefaultInstall.exe " + driverPath; // where driverPath is path of .inf file
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show(@"ADB / Fastboot / Google Android Driver has been installed");
    }
```

Comment: will this work without the user being logged in? Will it work with a user that does NOT have local administrator rights?